# Dot product of two vectors with respect to their sum and difference.

Tags: vectors

I am looking at some past [exam practice here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~giventh/5315_mt1_samples.pdf), and came across (8 on the worksheet):

> Express the dot product of two vectors $a \cdot b$ through the lengths
>   $M$ and $N$ of their sum and difference: $M = |a + b|$ and $N = |a - b|$.

My initial thought: Consider the dot product of $(a+b) \cdot (a+b)$ and expand:

$$(a+b) \cdot (a+b) = a^2 + 2a \cdot b + b^2$$

Now I have a connection between $2a \cdot b$ and $(a + b) \cdot (a + b)$ that I can hopefully use. So I tried solving for $2a \cdot b$:

$$(a + b) \cdot (a + b) - (a^2 + b^2) = 2a \cdot b$$

This is where I get stuck, Something that looked relatively promising involved using complex numbers:

$$(a + b) \cdot (a + b) - (a + ib) \cdot (a - ib) = 2 a \cdot b$$

So we have now two terms that *almost* look like $a + b$ and $a - b$, but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You started out with the right idea but took it in a wrong direction. How does $M$ relate to $(a+b)\cdot(a+b)$? Does that suggest something you might do with $(a-b)$?

Comment: I think I see what to do... $(a + b) \cdot (a + b) = M^2$. So similarly for $(a - b) \cdot (a - b)$  and you get $N^2$. Then consider expanding both terms (like I do above with $(a + b) \cdot (a + b)$ and then solving the system of equations I get:
$$\frac{(a+b) \cdot (a+b) - (a - b) \cdot (a - b)}{4}$$
$$\frac{M^2 - N^2}{4}$$

Comment: Does this sound right?

Comment: You’ve got the idea now.